# Magento - Rewrite Mage_Catalog_Block_Navigation

Tags: magento, overriding, magento-1.9

I am trying to rewrite the class Mage_Catalog_Block_Navigation, but I am unable to get it to work. When I refresh the website, (clear cache, etc...) and then check the system.log file, it is empty... (I have also tried adding code to the html, but that also did not work)

I currently have the following:

Company/Module/Block/Catalog/Navigation

```
<?php

class Company_Module_Block_Catalog_Navigation
    extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Navigation
{
    public function renderCategoriesMenuHtml($level = 0, $outermostItemClass = '', $childrenWrapClass = '')
    {
        Mage:log("running here");
        return parent::renderCategoriesMenuHtml($level, $outermostItemClass, $childrenWrapClass);

    }
}
```

config.xml

```
<global>
    ...
    <blocks>
        ...
        <catalog>
            <rewrite>
                <navigation>Company_Module_Block_Catalog_Navigation</navigation>
            </rewrite>
        </catalog>
        ...
    </blocks>
    ...
</global>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after searching further, it turns out that this block is not being used by the template that I am using, which would explain why the rewrite was not producing any results...

Answer (score 0):

config.xml

```
<global>
    <blocks>
      <catalog>
        <rewrite>
            <navigation>Company_Module_Block_Navigation</navigation>
        </rewrite>
    </catalog>
  </blocks>
</global>
```

your block file will be like.

```
<?php
   class Company_Module_Block_Navigation extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Navigation
   {
     // some code
   }
?>
```

OR you can simply try this code in block file

```
<?php
   require_once 'Mage/Catalog/block/Navigation.php';
   class Company_Module_Block_Navigation extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Navigation
```

Create Company_Module.xml at app/etc/modules

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
  <config>
    <modules>
     <Company_Module>
        <active>true</active>
        <codePool>local</codePool>
    </Company_Module>
   </modules>
  </config>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to register the block as follows:

In app/etc/local.xml

```
<global>
    <blocks>
        <catalog>
            <rewrite>
                <navigation>Company_Module_Block_Navigation</navigation>
            </rewrite>
        </catalog>
    </blocks>
</global>
```

Note that by adding above code in local.xml makes the rewrite global, and this is not always necessary to do, but this will helps you to determine whether the rewrite is working or not.

There is another possibility of extension conflicts on the website.

Comment: I tried the code above and that did not work. I guess that means than the rewrite is not working at all?

Comment: please create a php file in the root, and try printing following code : include 'app/Mage.php';
echo "<pre>";
print_r(Mage::app()->getConfig()->getXpath('//global//rewrite'));
exit;
if search your overide class here
If not present someother thing is not correct

Answer (score 0):

Try these steps:

1. Add these code into the file Company/Module/Block/Catalog/Navigation.php

   protected function _construct(){
   Mage::log("it's here");
   }
2. Create a subcategory
3. In the front-end, go to the subcategory, then check the log file

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a mistake in your code, in this line of code specifically:

```
Mage:log("running here");
```

it should be:

```
Mage::log("running here");
```